# keras evaluate on Data generator

Tags: keras, deep-learning

Iam using the evaluate function in keras to evaluate my models performance.
I trained a regression model using MSE as the metrics/objective function.

When I now load my validation data and evaluate the MSE, the value is constant, but when I shuffle my validation set before, the MSE score varies fairly well.

Does anybody know why shuffling the validation set leads to different model scores. I would have expect the score to be nearly the same (with some numerical instablity).

Thanks in advance,

cheers,

M

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thanks for your comment:

Here some code:

```
params_val = {'dim': (IMG_PX_SIZE,IMG_PX_SIZE),
                    'batch_size' : 1,
                        'n_channels': inChannel,
                    'shuffle': False,
                    'augment': False}  

X_val, y_val = shuffle(X_val, y_val)

dataGen_validation = DataGenerator2D(X_val, y_val, data_dir_val, **params_val)

model = keras.models.load_model(model_path)
model = model.layers[-2]

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001), loss='mse')
score = model.evaluate(dataGen_validation)
print(score)
```

My theory:

In my dataset there are a lot of easy examples and some difficult examples. As far as I have understood, the score is the mean value of the MSE over all batches. Depending on how the data is shuffled (i.ex. one batch with very easy examples only), the overall score might very.

Comment: You are right that this is the MSE on all batches, but you don't need to recompile your model. I'm not sure that this is the error here. Can you add the `shuffle` function? (and also you can remove the model.compile)

Comment: The shuffle function is already included in the above code. I only shuffle the data once before evaluating. Therefore the option is set to "false" in the datagenerator. (It would have worked for evaluating though).  When I remove the compile function I get en error that the model has to be compiled before using evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using generator for evaluation function (with tensorflow 2), it is likely that the the evaluation score you get is of the last step (batch) only, not your whole evaluation dataset. You can double check that using predict function.